# packery js same boxes different order not work

Tags: javascript, jquery, packery

I can't understand why in test 2 packery dosn't fill gaps as in test 1.

http://www.aboutluca.com/test-1/

http://www.aboutluca.com/test-2/

I only move box1 after box 2 in the html code

Comment: there is approximate calculation, so that why .. if you reduce the size of  the window you see that it fills in some cases

Comment: I think there is something is not working. When you reduce the window it fill the gaps because by media query i resize the boxes.